# When do we have Brouwer fixed points only on the corner?

Tags: functional-analysis, differential-topology, fixed-point-theorems

Suppose $f:[0,1]^n\rightarrow[0,1]^n$ is a continuous function. When does $f$ only have integral fixed points where each coordinate of the fixed point is either 0 or 1. In one-dimensional case, it means that the curve of $f$ never crosses the $45^\circ$ line, then we only have $f(0)=0$ or $f(1)=1$ as fixed points. Are there any results on this problem?

Comment: What do you mean by integral fixed points?

Comment: If you are looking for discrete versions of Brouwer fixed point theorem: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sperner%27s_lemma

Comment: @NelsonSchuback I mean each coordinate of the fixed point is either 0 or 1.

Comment: @LorenzoNajt I mean the function only has fixed points on the corner. In one-dimensional case, it means we only have f(0)=0 or f(1)=1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The characterization you give in 1 dimensions is a restatement of $\text{fixed points}(f) = \{ x : (x,y) \in \Delta \cap \Gamma_f \} \subseteq \text{Corners}$, where $\Delta$ is the diagonal (graph of identity function), and $\Gamma_f$ is the graph of $f$.

Here is why this is a restatement of your characterization of the $1$ dimensional case: $\Delta$ is the 45 degree slope line, and by 'never crossing' I think you mean that the graph of $f$ intersects $\Delta$ only at its endpoints, which are the points of $\Delta$ with $x$ coordinates given by the corners.

The equation $\text{fixed points}(f) = \{ x : (x,y) \in \Delta \cap \Gamma_f \subseteq X \times X\} $ is true for any function $f : X \to X$ - it follows formally by unwrapping the definitions.

So, you can generalize your characterization to the containment $\text{fixed points}(f) = \{ x : (x,y) \in \Delta \cap \Gamma_f \} \subseteq \text{Corners}$. This is equivalent to stating that $\Gamma_f$ intersects $\Delta$ only at the vertices of $\Delta$, since $\Delta$ is isomorphic to $[0,1]^n$ (as polytopes) under the map that projects to the $x$-coordinate.

Comment: I want to know whether there are more detailed results, maybe under additional assumptions on the function. I read from some textbook that there are topics about the orientation or degree of continuous functions. I think this problem might be related to that field.

Comment: @Surpass2019 Maybe you will be interested in this: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lefschetz_fixed-point_theorem ... one step in this caclulation is to describe the fixed points as the intersection of the diagonal with the graph. Orientations and similar come up. As far as I know (which is not far), there is nothing explicitly about the vertices. But the main point of the answer is show that the restatement you highlighted in 1D is a general fact.

Comment: @Surpass2019 Also, if you are looking for topological answers, maybe it would make more sense to ask for fixed points only on the boundary -- the reason being that the boundary of $[0,1]^n$ is a topological invariant, whereas the set of vertices is not. Both are generalizations of the 1D case you were looking at.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I'll read the material you provide.